HTML to PDF using flying Saucer Caron symbol not appearing
i am trying to convert an HTML file into a pdf. my HTML file has special chars like č ž (caron symbols).
the pdf is generated successfully however it seems that only the char 'c' with the caron symbol is not appearing in the PDF.
if i open the html i can see the text properly.
i am using spring boot to test it, but this can be executed the same way with a simple main in java
here is my simple code
 @GetMapping("/pdf")
    public ResponseEntity<String> generatePdf(@RequestParam("filePath") String filePath) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        File htmlFile = new File(filePath);
        String htmlContent = new String(Files.readAllBytes(htmlFile.toPath()));
        ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();

        // Path to a font that supports Central European characters and Unicode
        String fontPath = "c:/temp/poc-pdf/src/main/resources/templates/DejaVuSans.ttf";

        // Adding the font with Unicode encoding
        renderer.getFontResolver().addFont(fontPath, com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true);

        // Set the HTML content
        renderer.setDocumentFromString(htmlContent);
        renderer.layout();

        File file = new File("c:/temp/poc-pdf/src/main/resources/templates/pdf.pdf");
        try (OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
            renderer.createPDF(outputStream);
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok();
    }

HTML code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div>
    <p>
        čččččLorem ipsum dolor šit amet, consečtetur adipisčing elit. Vestibulum acčumsan metuš pharetra urna efficitur, ac congue justo commodo. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed et faucibus lectus. Suspendisse euismod tincidunt pretium. Aliquam porttitor ornare magna. Maecenas eget cursus arcu. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Praesent sodales commodo varius. Maecenas pellentesque velit vitae orci eleifend egestas. Aenean aliquet elit lorem, non maximus sapien efficitur a.
    </p>

</div>
</body>
</html>

i tried different fonts all of them give the same result of the missing symbol.

What happens with &#x010D; in the html?

I think your problem arises where you create a string from a byte array.
String htmlContent = new String(Files.readAllBytes(htmlFile.toPath()));

Since you aren't passing a charset to the string constructor, the default charset is used (will be different on unix/linux vs windows). See Charset.defaultCharset().
I'm guessing the default charset is not the same as the html file's encoding which causes issues with special characters.
Option 1 - pass a charset to the string constructor
Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8")); // TODO use the same as the file encoding
byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(htmlFile.toPath());
String htmlContent = new String(bytes, charset);
renderer.setDocumentFromString(htmlContent);

Option 2-  skip the conversion to string and use a reader instead
Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8")); // TODO use the same as the file encoding
try (Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(htmlFile), charset) {
   renderer.setDocumentFromReader(reader);
}


hi lance, thanks for replying.
i tried the changes you suggested and i got the same result.
the issue here, is only with a specific character. other symbols are working fine.
the fonts i used all have this char and for fact other chars have the same symbol and they get painted.

@msaba it sounds like the HTML is using the ISO-8859-15 charset and you are using ISO-8859-1 or UTF-8 - or perhaps the HTML is using ISO-8859-1 and you're using ISO-8859-15 by default. My suspicion arises from the fact that ISO-8859-15 supports various European characters such as š and ž but not č - which is the letter that you're missing, even though you get the other letters.

i added   to the HTML to make sure its aligned with the char set. but still only the 'c' is not printed.
i switched to a chromium based solution which works perfectly fine even without adding the charset to the html. but i would like to find a solution for this.

which editor are you using to edit the html? Does the editor tell you it's UTF-8 encoding? Adding <meta charset="UTF-8"> to your xml doesn't change the encoding used by your editor.

First it is nice to immediately use Unicode. I see two issues here.
As already said, the encoding defaults to the platform encoding. Which is not portible.
    String htmlContent = new String(Files.readAllBytes(htmlFile.toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    String htmlContent = Files.readString(htmlFile.toPath())); // Default UTF-8

And the delivered HTML file should indicate its encoding too - to be consistent.
The actual text encoding must be checked.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <p>
        čččččLorem ipsum dolor šit amet, consečtetur adipisčing elit. Vestibulum acčumsan metuš pharetra urna efficitur, ac congue justo commodo. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed et faucibus lectus. Suspendisse euismod tincidunt pretium. Aliquam porttitor ornare magna. Maecenas eget cursus arcu. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Praesent sodales commodo varius. Maecenas pellentesque velit vitae orci eleifend egestas. Aenean aliquet elit lorem, non maximus sapien efficitur a.
    </p>

</div>
</body>
</html>


Reacting on the comment
The fact that šž are shown but č not rings a bell.

In Latin-1, ISO-8859-1, šžč are not present.
In Windows Latin-1, Code Page 1252, šž are in the added block U+0080 .. U+009F. Here also č goes missing.

This seems to indicate that somewhere Windows Latin-1 is involved, maybe in the font rendering. Inspect the properties of the generated PDF, fonts and such. You already took some care. I know using Unicode for PDF generation needs extra config, but I do not know.

hi Joop,
i changed the email template to include the utf, i also tried to add in the code something like this:

and always the same results, other special chars are all appearing but just the c with the cron doesnt.

Added to the answer what is special here. Maybe someone else sees it. In a PDF reader compare the document properties. Maybe compare them with a Word PDF export or such.
